# What are the requirements for someone to deposit a check into your bank account?

Tags: united-states, banking

I recently opened a checking account and gave my account number to my new boss. What will my boss need to do to be able to deposit a check into my checking account? Can someone deposit into your account with only your account number??

Comment: Removing cash needs your explicit approval. Depositing generally doesn't, if the account and routing number are known... and remember, every time you write a check you're handing someone that same information. I don't see anything you need to worry about here; it sounds like standard direct-deposit.

Comment: What country, please edit and add country tag. How is the deposit happening, electronic, check, cash etc.

Comment: I've tried to deposit a check in my wife's account (before we were married) and her bank wouldn't let me do it without her consent.

Comment: Am in new jersey. Its a check @Dheer

Answer (score 8):

**Assumptions**: you're in the United States, you gave an account *and routing* number, and your boss will be making direct (i.e. electronic) deposits. In particular, I assume you're not asking whether your boss can walk up to the counter and deposit a check made out to you.

Under those assumptions, the answer is yes. Your boss can deposit your paycheck/bonus/expense reimbursement/whatever directly into your account. It is routine for employers to do so. Sometimes the employer will ask for a voided check, but not always; sometimes they just need the account and routing numbers.

Comment: In many companies the employee can enter this information via the HR or payroll  system. The employee just needs to enter the routing number and account number. Some of these systems allow you to specify multiple accounts. In some systems they will lookup the routing number in a database and provide you with the name of the bank/credit union so you can see that you entered the value correctly.

Answer (score 6):

> Can someone deposit into your account with only your account number?

Yes. If I have a copy of your blank check or the routing and account number, I can make a deposit. 
Years ago, I had a tenant who always paid late, and often bounced checks. To avoid the bounce, I'd go the bank that was where he had his account. One time, he was short $5. i.e. he had $620, and the rent was $625. I handed the teller $5 and a deposit ticket, made the deposit and got my money.

Comment: Did the tenant tell you he was $5 short or was it the bank teller?

Comment: The teller leaked it to me.

Comment: Wow. Did some more digging - it seems that account balance info is not especially well protected by privacy laws. Not that I'd be particularly bothered if people tried to find out mine, it just surprises me that it can be as easy as [asking about a check](https://www.finweb.com/banking-credit/when-can-others-see-my-bank-accounts-balance.html).

Comment: Without a doubt, disclosing was probably not kosher. But. Had I simply presented the check for cashing, in person, the teller would have disclosed insufficient balance and handed it back. Deposited at an ATM, we both would have had a fee charged.